# Routes Error laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

i have an issue with a basic "forgot password" method. I'm sending email to myself with postman and write this to log file. Then i copy this link and paste it and got this error. The strange thing that it's working 1 out of 100 times, but the rest times i got this error. I can't even go to mydomain.com/password/reset with browser, it redirects my to mydomain.com/ with this error.

I have this route in my php artisan route:list and here is my routes:

```
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
```

Can't understand what is going on and why it's sometimes working and sometimes not.
If i try to go to this link with GET request from Postman - i will see th HTML page with form to send email.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: post the whole route file.

Comment: can't post full route file here because it's too long. 
You can check it here: http://pastebin.com/Emawbx1d

Answer (score 2):

in your code "password/reset" routes 3 time define so it is override and get last one so please give proper name of routes